How to correctly trace all outboud Node.js request on server apps with Express
I try many library, last library I try was global-tunnel-ng, but still have no result. Usually I use fiddler to trace various request, my Fiddler listen port 8888, therefore I try to use
  var globalTunnel = require('global-tunnel-ng');
  globalTunnel.initialize({
    host: 'ipv4.fiddler',
    port: 8888,
  });

  // my various request to Google, to AWS and more

  globalTunnel.end()

I expected to see all request on Fiddler, but there are nothing any request on Fiddler panel. 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' as ProxyURL also don't working. What I doing wrong?

Node.js ignores proxy settings by default, unlike many languages (see https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8381) so it can be challenging to capture this traffic.
There are various libraries that can do this for some cases (global-agent covers most recent APIs - but not all of them, e.g. it won't capture requests via Undici & Node's fetch global).
In future, this may be slowly resolved by https://github.com/nodejs/undici/issues/1650 and other similar efforts, but I suspect that won't be universal any time soon.
I also ran into this, and Fiddler and other alternatives are not very helpful here, so I built my own open-source HTTP debugging alternative app which can handle Node.js interception automatically. Take a look at https://httptoolkit.com/javascript/ for more info. If you use this instead of Fiddler, you can open a terminal in one click, and then outgoing traffic from any Node process started in that terminal will be intercepted automatically, for all cases I'm aware of (http and https modules, fetch, Unidici, etc).

Hello, @Tim, can you tools in free version intercept FETCH request and RESPONSE(BLOB) request from Node.JS? - currently I need exactly the same for debugging my program. Also I doing request to AWS and SQL - but this is not very interesting, because AWS has own workable interceptor.

You can intercept, fully view & manually modify all traffic from all sources in the free version. If you find any outgoing traffic that's not captured, that's a bug. The paid version primarily adds extra rules to automatically modify traffic, import/export features, and advanced configuration, you shouldn't need any of that.
